# Bootstrap notification - JS function fades notification only on first iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following JS function that creates a div with a bootstrap class:

```
function showDiv() {
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = '<div id="newAlert" class="alert alert-info">Hello</div>'
    document.body.appendChild(div);
$("#newAlert").delay(3000).fadeOut();
```

An HTML button  will trigger this function and display a bootstrap notification on the screen, which will fade out after 3 seconds.

The problem is that after the first fade, clicking the button again will make the notification appear again, but will not fade out on the second button click. I need the notification to appear and fade on each button click without reloading the page.

I initially tried implementing an 'if 1==1' statement around the jquery portion, but that didn't change anything.

Could someone point me in the right direction as to why the notification only fades once? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.fadeOut()` hides the matched elements by fading them to transparent. For the second time there will be two `#newAlert` present in the DOM.

```js
function showDiv() {
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = '<div id="newAlert" class="alert alert-info">Hello</div>'
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  $("#newAlert").delay(3000).fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showDiv()">Alert!</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The element must be removed from the DOM. .remove is not a queued method, therefor you'll need a timeout in this case.

```
function showDiv() {
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = '<div id="newAlert" class="alert alert-info">Hello</div>'
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    $("#newAlert").delay(3000).fadeOut();

    setTimeout(function() {
    $('#newAlert').remove();
  }, 3500);
}
```

The extra 500ms accounts for the fadeout.
Edit: Forgot about setting the 2nd parameter of fadeOut method. However I'll leave my answer since it helps emphasize the point.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the div when the fade out is completed

```js
function showDiv() {
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = '<div id="newAlert" class="alert alert-info">Hello</div>'
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    $("#newAlert").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow", function() {
      document.body.removeChild(div);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button onClick="showDiv()">Show div</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated!